# Pagination issue after moving to new server

Tags: php, pagination

I recently moved my website to a new server. After the website had been moved the PHP pagination stopped working. None of the code has changed. Is there any configuration changes that need to be made?

Below is the code:

```
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
            mysql_select_db("playstat_page") or die(mysql_error());
            //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 
            if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
            { 
            $pagenum = 1; 
            } 
            //count the number of results 
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 
            //number of results displayed per page 
            $page_rows = 20; 
            //page number of our last page 
            $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
            //makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 
            if ($pagenum < 1)  
            { 
            $pagenum = 1; 
            } 
            elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
            { 
            $pagenum = $last; 
            } 
            //sets the range to display in our query 
            $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
            $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY ID DESC $max") or die(mysql_error()); 
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p ))                 
            {
            $posted = date('F j, Y g:i a', strtotime($info["Posted"]));
                Print "<p>{$info["Head"]}</p><br></br>";
            } 
            if ($pagenum == 1) 
            {
            } 
            else 
            {
            $previous = $pagenum-1;
            Print "<div id='pagenav'>
                    <ul style='float: left; margin-left: -25px;'>
                        <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'>First</a></li> 
                        <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'>Previous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>";
            } 
            if ($pagenum == $last) 
            {
            } 
            else 
            {
            $next = $pagenum+1;
            Print "<div id='pagenav'>
                    <ul style='float:right'>
                        <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next</a></li>
                        <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>";
            }
```

Comment: If the pagination is in your code we won't be able to tell you anything since there might be a dozen of changes that might interfere with any part of your script when you change from one php version to another

Comment: Add Code, What Warnings Are You Getting?

Comment: Are you using PHP to do your pagination, are you reliant on htaccess? More information is needed. At the moment, you're telling us the car is broken, but do not tell what broke.

Comment: This is an imposible question to answer.

Comment: Is there anything else that isn't working?

Comment: Did you bother doing any basic debugging yourself? Check error logs for anything relevant? Turn on display_errors/error_reporting to see if PHP's barfing on something? Since you've provided absolutely nothing of any use other than "new server", we can't help you.

Comment: Try turning your monitor on and off. It that doesn't work. Turn off the monitor while standing on one leg. That should fix it.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the code. Everything else is working fine. When you hit the next button it returns you to the top of the page instead of showing the older entries. The website is playstationcore.com

Comment: Where is `$pagenum` coming from? I don't see it being defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It easy. In your php.ini there must be the setting for that. Check phpinfo() to make sure it's enabled, see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the new server does not have the `register_globals` turned on, and you seem to be getting the requested page from some variable.

Replace

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
{ 
    $pagenum = 1; 
}
```

With

```
if (!isset($_GET['pagenum']))
{
    $pagenum = 1;
}
else
{
    $pagenum = intval($_GET['pagenum']);
}
```

Edit: `register_globals` says that globals as defined through the HTTP request (say, all those $_GET,$_POST,..) are automatically `extract()`ed such that (as an example):

`$_GET['pagenum']` is accessible as `$pagenum`

It's often considered a bad practice and source of errors (not mentioning problematic concerning security) to have the setting turned on.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you. I really appreciate it. It was driving me crazy!